# $ sign and calculation in python

Tags: python, subtraction

I'm trying to calculate a value that is in $ sign, and subtract from it. Not sure exactly how...sorry if basic question, but thank you very much.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


urleth = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(urleth)
content = page.read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
valeth = soup.find("span", {"id": "quote_price"}).decode_contents(formatter="html")
print("Ethereum price is ", valeth)
print(valeth)
```

Above is Good

Below, not sure. 
Valeth shows a $ sign, and now sure how to subtract with $100 that has dollar sign.

```
value = (valeth - $100.00)
print(value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the $100.00 to 100.00 then, you can do everything.
suppose,

```
var = '$100.00'
var = float(var[1:])
value = (valeth - var)
print(value)
```